# Unity crashes when using Instantiate inside for loop

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, crash

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnIll : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberIll;
    public GameObject illPrefab;
    public Vector2 pos;
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberIll; i++)
        {
          pos=new Vector2(Random.Range(-1000,1001),Random.Range(-1000,1001));
            Instantiate(illPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

No matter what I choose as numberIll, the Unity will crash. I think it goes in an infinite loop but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Unless you increase `numberIll` for each prefab you Instantiate I don't see how this loop should become infinite. Did you try to set Brakepoints and debug the code line by line?

Comment: @derHugo Everything works fine until I use Instantiate. Maybe there is something wrong with it. I don't want to use Coroutines. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Is there maybe a component attached to that prefab that causes the issue? I don't think the problem sits in the code you provided

Comment: @derHugo I have another script attached to the prefab but it is inactive. Besides that there is nothing else.

Comment: Hm sounds odd .. maybe attach the other script anyway just in case. Are there any other scripts in the scene that might be interfering with the one you provided or the Instantiated objects?

Comment: @derHugo there is nothing else in the scene just the prefab and the main camera, attaching the other script does nothing. It seems that unity simply can't enter playmode and it just stays like that.

Comment: newVector2 - add the space

Comment: And start using any IDE to avoid syntax mistakes

Comment: @caxapexac not a problem with that when I asked the question i mistyped. In the project it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: every object created keeps doing the for loop so it just creates lots of gameobjects. I used coroutine and it worked.

Comment: What? Is this script attached to the prefab?

Comment: @Draco18s No, if you attach it to the prefab it will create objects exponentially(e.g. 1,2,4,8,16,...) so you have to attach it to an empty game object

Comment: Well, yes, I know that. I'm trying to figure out how changing your code to a coroutine solved the problem. Because that should have precisely zero effect.

Comment: @Draco18s well, when I was using the for loop the script WAS attached to the prefab, then I used a coroutine and attached the script to an empty gameobject.

Comment: So, in reality, the coroutine wasn't the solution, but the empty game object.

Comment: @Draco18s Yeah, sorry for my bad explanation.